# What other geometry processing data structures are there?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, geometry, data-structure

I essentially know of 2 geometry processing data structures. one is the half edge (which has some really nice properties, but can't represent non manifold meshes nor tet meshes).

The other is an extended adjacency list representation of the graph connectivity that also stores faces and edges.

Are there more?

Comment: Full edge epresentation where the edge has a list of connections.

Comment: Are you mainly (only?) interested in 3D geometry or is 2D also of interest?

Comment: 2D is acceptable, but I am definitely more interested in 3D

Comment: My favorite 3D data structure is combinatorial map (cf. for example one implementation in CGAL here https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Combinatorial_map/).

Comment: You could look at [Data structures for simplicial complexes: an analysis and a comparison](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.92.9969&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by de Floriani and Hui; it covers structures in 2D and 3D, but if you want to represent something other than triangular / tetrahedral meshes there are other things out there.